# Ruby: escape escape sequence?

Tags: ruby, string

There is a string:

```
str = "foo\nbar"
```

How can I escape it to:

```
'foo\nbar'
```

?

I noticed `"#{str}"` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.inspect` Should do it for you

Comment: `"foo\nbar".inspect` returns `"\"foo\\nbar\""`. It adds double quotes to the string that weren't originally there.

Answer (score 2):

Add another `\`:

```
"foo\\nbar" == 'foo\nbar'  #=> true
```

Single-quoted strings do not have interpolation, so `#{str}` does nothing special in them.